# PHP: What is the fastest and easiest way to get the last item of an array?

Tags: php, micro-optimization

What is the fastest and easiest way to get the last item of an array whether be indexed array , associative array or multi-dimensional array?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
$myArray = array( 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 );

echo end($myArray);
```

prints "1"

Comment: and to get the last element's key... (to update it)
`end($myArray); $key=key($myArray);`

Answer (score 2):

[array_pop()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

It removes the element from the end of the array. If you need to keep the array in tact, you could use this and then append the value back to the end of the array. `$array[] = $popped_val`

Comment: Is popping and then appending better than `end($array)`?  If no, probably best not to suggest doing that.  If it is ever better, that's surprising and it would be interesting to explain why that could be, and under what circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$arrayname[count(arrayname)-1]
```

Comment: This is wrong, it only works with ordered numerical array, ie it won't work with shuffled or associative array.

Answer (score 1):

I would say `array_pop` In the documentation: [array_pop](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

> array_pop — Pop the element off the end of array

Answer (score 1):

Lots of great answers. Consider writing a function if you're doing this more than once:

```
function array_top(&$array) {
    $top = end($array);
    reset($array); // Optional
    return $top;
}
```

Alternatively, depending on your temper:

```
function array_top(&$array) {
    $top = array_pop($array);
    $array[] = $top; // Push top item back on top
    return $top;
}
```

(`$array[] = ...` is preferred to `array_push()`, cf. [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).)

Answer (score 0):

For an associative array:

```
$a= array('hi'=> 'there', 'ok'=> 'then');
list($k, $v) = array(end(array_keys($a)), end($a));
var_dump($k);
var_dump($v);
```

Edit: should also work for numeric index arrays

Comment: `$v=end($a); $k=key($a);` (order IS relevant) seems faster to me.