# How to get the last item of an array in PHP

Tags: php, html, pdo

After i get data from database i want to get the last item in the array.

my code is like this:

```
<?php
....

while($show=$getComments->fetch()){
//here i list all items 
//but i want to catch the
//last item to change its DIV color.

}

...
?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: What is the fastest and easiest way to get the last item of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927029/php-what-is-the-fastest-and-easiest-way-to-get-the-last-item-of-an-array)

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PHP end() function.

> This function is used to get the last item in the array. The information of this function is fully available on PHP official website you can see below by clicking the link

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

Syntax : $variable = end($array);

Here is what you need :-

```
<?php

while($show = $getComments->fetch()) {
    $last_item_of_array = end($show);
    //the variable($last_item_of_array) above is the last item of the array
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use array_pop();

```
<?php
$show = array_pop($getComments->fetch())
?>
```

You can see that array pop will remove the last item from the array and return that value to your variable.
Check out the php documentation here!
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php